# How I can add more than one QJsonObject to a QJsonDocument

Tags: json, qt

I want to add more than one `QJsonObject` to a `QJsonDocument`.
Is this possible?

It should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "objID": "obj1"
        //... Some other parameter
    },
    {
        "objID": "obj2"
        //...Some other parameter
    }
]
```

I tried this:

```
QJsonDocument(obj1).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
QJsonDocument(obj2).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
```

But it produces invalid JSON.

Comment: I want to write Json file in below format. Is it possible? { { "objID": "obj1" //... Some other parameter }, { "objID": "obj2" //...Some other parameter } }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A JSON document has only one root value. In the example you gave, that value is an array, which contains two objects

To get that in Qt, you'd say:

```
QJsonArray array;
array << obj1;
array << obj2;
QJsonDocument(array).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
```

Comment: I want to write Json file in below format. Is it possible?
`{
    {
        "objID": "obj1"
        //... Some other parameter
    },
    {
        "objID": "obj2"
        //...Some other parameter
    }
}`

Comment: That is not (valid) JSON; the {} means objects, which have to be { name: value, ...}. You could get [ { "objID": "obj1" //... Some other parameter }, { "objID": "obj2" //...Some other parameter } ], which would be an array of objects.

Comment: Its a valid Json file. Json file may contain JArray, JObject or both. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55193946/how-i-can-add-more-than-one-qjsonobject-to-a-qjsondocument-qt) for more info.

Comment: That one is valid: it has key names. Jobject has to be { name1: value1, name2: value2 }. Theirs has placeholder names "Obj1", "Obj2", and meets this. Yours asked for { value1, value2 }, which is not valid.

Comment: I haven't ask for  { value1, value2 } ? It may be you misunderstood my problem.