# How I can add more than one QJsonObject to a QJsonDocument - Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt, qjson, qjsonobject

I want to add more than one QJsonObject and not QJsonArray to a QJsonDocument. Is this possible? It should look like this:

```
{
    "Obj1" : {
        "objID": "111",
        "C1" : {
            "Name":"Test1",
            "Enable" : true
        }
    },
    "Obj2" : {
        "objID": "222",
        "C2" : {
            "Name":"Test2",
            "Enable" : true
        }
    }
}
```

I have refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411339/how-i-can-add-more-than-one-qjsonobject-to-a-qjsondocument) but I dont want to use `JsonArray`. Only want to use `JsonObject` . I have also refer many more answer over here, but dint find any solution.

I tried this :

```
QTextStream stream(&file);
for(int idx(0); idx < obj.count(); ++idx)
{
    QJsonObject jObject;
    this->popData(jObject); // Get the Filled Json Object
    QJsonDocument jDoc(jObject);
    stream << jDoc.toJson() << endl;
}
file.close();
```

**Output**

```
{
    "Obj1" : {
        "objID": "111",
        "C1" : {
            "Name":"Test1",
            "Enable" : true
        }
    }
}

{
    "Obj2" : {
        "objID": "222",
        "C2" : {
            "Name":"Test2",
            "Enable" : true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your `popData` function implemented? Could you write an MCVE that constructs such a malformed `QJsonDocument`?

Comment: I am passing `QJsonObject` as reference in the `popData()` function and get filled object that contains `"Obj1" : {
        "objID": "111",
        "C1" : {
            "Name":"Test1",
            "Enable" : true
        }
    }` one object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the loop, with each iteration you are creating a new JSON document and writing it to the stream. That means that they all are multiple independent documents. You need to create one `QJsonObject` (the parent object) and populate it with all the other objects as part of it i.e. nested objects. Then, you'll have only one object and after the loop you can create a `QJsonDocument` and use it to write to file.

Here's your code that creates a new document with each iteration:

```
for ( /* ... */ )
{
    // ...
    QJsonDocument jDoc(jObject);        // new document without obj append
    stream << jDoc.toJson() << endl;    // appends new document at the end
    // ...
}
```

Here's what you need to do:

```
// Create a JSON object
// Loop over all the objects
//    Append objects in loop
// Create document after loop
// Write to file
```

Here's a small working **example**:

```
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    const std::map<QString, QString> data
    {
        { "obj1", R"({ "id": 1, "info": { "type": 11, "code": 111 } })" },
        { "obj2", R"({ "id": 2, "info": { "type": 22, "code": 222 } })" }
    };

    QJsonObject jObj;
    for ( const auto& p : data )
    {
        jObj.insert( p.first, QJsonValue::fromVariant( p.second ) );
    }

    QJsonDocument doc { jObj };
    qDebug() << qPrintable( doc.toJson( QJsonDocument::Indented ) );

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
{
    "obj1": "{ \"id\": 1, \"info\": { \"type\": 11, \"code\": 111 } }",
    "obj2": "{ \"id\": 2, \"info\": { \"type\": 22, \"code\": 222 } }"
}
```